# haystack/elasticsearch: trying to find "s04e07"

Tags: numbers, elasticsearch, django-haystack

i have a kinda weird problem with haystack/elasticsearch trying to find tv episodes stored in my database based on a string like this: 's04e07' which means season 4 episode 7 and is a kind of standard format, but the search index has its problems with that.

Trying a few different things it looks like numbers are not indexed in EdgeNgramFields.
In a CharField i can only find exact word matches like '2013' if contained in the titel, but i have no luck finding 's04e07'.

How do i get my results out of the index?
How could i possibly change the hardcoded default mapping in haystack to index my stuff correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote about haystack a few days ago, I would suggest reading that one first:

[Django Haystack Distinct Value for Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034718/django-haystack-distinct-value-for-field/20052905#20052905)

It's not directly on point, but my advice here is the same. Stop using haystack.

Haystack comes with an outofthebox edgengram and ngram analyzers, which is cool, except these analyzers don't work in nearly all use cases.

They will especially not work in yours because you are mixing numbers and chars.

But my first question is, why can't you index the data like this:

```
"season":1
"episode":1
```

And then at search time break down the users search into the above format?

If that isn't possible, you can still PUT a mapping manually without letting haystack do it for you (which I recommend highly anyway because it's mappings are not correct). It's pretty easy to do with elasticutils.

Keep in mind, I don't think edgengram is exactly what you want here in any event. because it only grams from the edge and is most useful for autocompletes, for example if someone is typing s04e and you want to display a list of possible matches.

So, this depends on how users will query the data. Will it always be the above string whole, or parts of the string, or will they sometimes search for e07 and you want to show all seasons with episode 7's?

The last possibility here is to just index it as normal (haystack will choose snowball) and use prefix queries / regex queries to get what you want.

Comment: i could go with extra index fields like suggested, BUT the above is just one of a row of similar problems .. the same goes for kinda unindexable strings like 720p/1080p and other stuff ..

i just like to know if an how it might be possible to get haystack/elasticsearch to find this stuff. For now my best solution is to go with double indexing as ngram (autocomplete) and char (numbers) version .. feels weird, but kinda gets the job done